# How to create and depend on an async JavaScript module?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, module, promise

There are several ways to create and import modules in JavaScript, but as far as I know they are all designed to load synchronously.

To demonstrate the problem I'm facing, I've created these two example CommonJS modules:

```
var Dependency;
(function (Dependency) {

    Dependency.data = 'Not loaded!';

    function doSomethingAsync() {
        // Fetching data from server...
        setTimeout(function () {
            Dependency.data = 'Loaded!';
        }, 2000);
    }

})(Dependency = exports.Dependency || (exports.Dependency = {}));
```

This module contains some async code, and cannot (/should not) be used while 'loading'. When trying to use the `data` from another module, it will not work:

```
var dep = require("./dependency");
var MyModule;
(function (MyModule) {

    function useDependency() {
        // Logs out 'Not loaded!'
        console.log(dep.Dependency.data);
    }

    MyModule.useDependency = useDependency;

})(MyModule = exports.MyModule || (exports.MyModule = {}));
```

Calling `MyModule.useDependency()` will show that the `Dependency` is not usable yet.

I am looking for a way to implement a generic structure for this to use in my projects.

---

A solution I came up with was using (ES6) promises. I gave each module a `load()` function which all return a promise. So in this case I would call `Dependency.load().then(MyModule.load)` from some sort of entry file. That would work fine in this case as `useDependency()` will print out `Loaded!` now. Although I'm not sure if this is the best solution as I'll need to keep track of all these dependencies manually.

---

**So my question is**: What is the best way to handle such async module dependencies? And is there any standardized way of doing this?

Comment: `What is the best way to create such an async module dependency tree?` - you've posted a "stick" and want help with a "tree" - the best solution is one that works for your projects overall design, I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am looking for a way to implement a generic structure for this to use in my projects.

Since you are using Common.js modules, the best and easiest approach is to make each export (of a module using async initialisation) a promise itself.

(Of course, if it is only one function in the module, then only that function should return a promise)

```
// dependency.js
var promise = new Promise(resolve => {
    // Fetching data from server...
    setTimeout(function () {
        resolve('Loaded!')
    }, 2000);
});
module.exports = promise.then(data => {
    …
    return {
        data,
        …
    };
});
```

```
// mymodule.js
module.exports = Promise.all([
    require("./dependency"),
    …
]).then(([dep, …]) => {
    …
    return {
        useDependency() {
            console.log(dep.data); // 'Loaded'
        },
        …
    };
});
```

```
// main.js
require('mymodule').then(MyModule => {
    MyModule.useDependency();
});
```

Notice that this does not work with cyclic dependencies.

And this advise is completely void for ES6 modules, which currently don't feature global asynchrony.